Обрезать в Text сверху пустое место
Подскажите как обрезать в Text сверху пустое место?
    Column {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource("Image.png"),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            text = "Убрать отступ сверху",
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            style = TextStyle(background = Color.Gray)
        )
    } 


Пробовал обрезать так
        val cropShape = GenericShape { size: Size, _: LayoutDirection ->
            addRect(Rect(0f, 8f, size.width, size.height))
        }

            Text(
                text = "Убрать отступ сверху",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                style = TextStyle(background = Color.Gray),
                modifier = Modifier.clip(cropShape)
            )

Обрезает но отступ остается


Может вот так как-то? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975881/5479247

Костыль конечно но работает.
Column {
    Text(
        text = "Hello, World!",
        fontSize = 42.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .zIndex(2f)
    )
    Text(
        text = "Example",
        fontSize = 42.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(34.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true, align = Alignment.CenterVertically)
            .background(color = Color.Cyan)
            .zIndex(1f)
    )


